# Java, add image when there is a specific number

Tags: java, netbeans

Sorry for not being clear enough. English is my second language.

I have done a complet code down here to generate four random numbers and then printing out four images (image two).

I have image one, two, thre, four, five and six.

```
Random tarning = new Random();

String strOutput="";
int nummer;


for(int i=1; i<=4; i++){
   nummer = 1+tarning.nextInt(6);
   strOutput=strOutput+" "+nummer;
}

lblOutput.setText(strOutput);


jPanel2.setLayout(new java.awt.GridLayout(1,6));          
for(int n=0;n<=3;n++){
   x[n].setIcon(new ImageIcon("two.png")); 
   jPanel2.add(x[n]);
   jPanel2.revalidate();
   jPanel2.repaint();
 }
```

When it prints out like 1 2 3 4, How can i get image One to print when number one comes and then image two when number two comes etc.

Comment: What do you mean by `label`?

Comment: I have done a random number generator (dice game), and i print the x amount of numbers to the label.

    strOutput=strOutput+" "+nummer;

The strOutput is it that i print to the label. 

I'm pretty knew to java.

Comment: what's x? Where's your label? You do mean a "JLabel" object by "label", right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you mean JLabel:

```
String diceResult = jLabelDiceResult.getText();
String[] parsedResults = diceResult.split(" ");
for (int i=0; i<parsedResults.length; i++)
{
    switch (Integer.parseInt(y[i]))
    {
        case 1: jPanel2.add(x[i]);
            break;
        case 2: jPanel2.add(x[i]);
            break;
    }
}
```

Edit: Edited jPanel1 to jPanel2 in response to PM 77-1's comment.

Comment: Did you mean `jPanel2` in `case 2`?

Comment: i dont understand the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a map for mapping numbers to image name. Like :

```
Map<String, String> imageMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
imageMap.put("1","one.png");
imageMap.put("2","two.png"); // similarly for others
```

Then you can use: `String[] nums = label.split(" "); // split on space`

And finally: `x[n].setIcon(new ImageIcon(imageMap.get(nums[i]));`